# Insert buttons into sendSweetAlert message in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Friends in the code below show a message alert, if the option "Exclude farms" was selected. However, I would like to know if it is possible to insert two buttons (Yes and NO) in this alert? The functionality of these buttons is still under development. The executable code is below.

```
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      radioButtons(
        "filter1", 
        h3("Select properties"), 
        choiceValues = c(1, 2),
        choiceNames = list(
          tagList(
            tags$span("All properties"),
            tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "icon1", style = "color: blue;")
          ), 
          tagList(
            tags$span("Exclude properties"),
            tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "icon2", style = "color: blue;")
          )
        ),
        selected = 1
      ),


      selectInput("filter2", h3("Select farms"),
                  choices = list("All farms" = 1, 
                                 "Exclude farms" = 2),
                  selected = 1),
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if(input$filter2 == 2){
      sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "Warning!",
        text = "Change filter options selected above",
        type = "warning"
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: An alternative for interactive popups to the sweet alert is `modalDialog` from plain vanilla `{shiny}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add additional HTML elements with the `text` argument in `sendSweetAlert` by using a `tags$div`. See more options/info in the examples with `?sendSweetAlert` (you can put widgets and plot/table outputs too).

The simpler way for this situation is to simply pass a character vector of length 2 to the `btn_labels` argument depending on what you are wanting to do. Here is the app with both solutions combined in to one alert so it has two sets of yes and no buttons. Remove the “text” argument in the sendSweetAlert function to just have one set of the default yes/no

```
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      radioButtons(
        "filter1", 
        h3("Select properties"), 
        choiceValues = c(1, 2),
        choiceNames = list(
          tagList(
            tags$span("All properties"),
            tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "icon1", style = "color: blue;")
          ), 
          tagList(
            tags$span("Exclude properties"),
            tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "icon2", style = "color: blue;")
          )
        ),
        selected = 1
      ),


      selectInput("filter2", h3("Select farms"),
                  choices = list("All farms" = 1, 
                                 "Exclude farms" = 2),
                  selected = 1),
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if(input$filter2 == 2){
      sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "Warning!",
        btn_labels = c("Yes", "No"),
        text = tags$div(h5("Change filter options selected above"), 
                        actionButton("yes", "YES"),
                        actionButton("no", "NO")
                      ),

        type = "warning"
      )
    }
  })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks friend for the answer. But there is no way to leave just two buttons, one Yes and the other No. Because the way it is, in the alert message, it appears twice Yes and twice No.

Comment: Remove the “text =“ argument in the sendSweetAlert. This example shows two different approaches to adding buttons to the alert combined into one. Apologies if that was not clear.

Comment: Ah ok friend, I hadn't read your answer properly, I was seeing the code more. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Definitely. I updated  the answer to make it more clear for anyone else as well

Comment: Friend, sorry for the inconvenience but would you know how to answer this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962692/adjust-shiny-textoutput). Thank you very much!